# Solving the modular equation $a(a^{k-1}+k) \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ motivated by a few numerical examples

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Characterize the solutions to the modular equation

$$a(a^{k -1} +k)\equiv 0 \pmod{n} $$

for $a, k, n \in \mathbb{N}$. There are no restrictions on these values as the task is to characterize all solutions. The motivation for this question is from the case $a=4, k=13, n=497$, then

$$4^{13} \equiv 497 - 4\cdot 13 \equiv -4\cdot 13 \pmod{497} $$

and with a quick script, we can find a lot of other examples, such as $a = 2, k = 23, n = 91$, but I have no idea how to characterize all the solutions to this equation.

This is not a homework question, just something I am wondering about. As a starter idea, maybe a construction similar to the following (I'm not suggesting this is a fruitful direction): choosing primes $p_1, \cdots, p_m > a$ be $m$ primes and let $k = 1 + \text{lcm} (p_1 -1, p_2 -1, \dots, p_m-1, p_1 \cdots p_m)$, then for each $i$, we have
$$a^{k-1} - k \equiv 0 \pmod{p_i} $$
and then something like CRT might give an angle on the original question.

Comment: One characterization of all solutions is: $a$ and $k$ can be arbitrary, and then $n$ can be any divisor of the integer $a(a^{k-1}+k)$. (And tons of examples can be found that way.) If that is not a suitable characterization, what properties do you want the characterization to have?

Comment: Which (if any) of $\,a,n,k\,$ are fixed (given)?